# Multiple google-services.json for Firebase Analytics and send to different projects

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I want to send the same data from Firebase Analytics to two different projects.

I read that you can use different

```
app/
    google-services.json
    src/development/google-services.json
    src/release/google-services.json
    ...
```

But I want to keep practically the two files in the same path (what happen if I have two versions of google-services.json without putting the flavor of compilation?) and making the reports in two projects, I can use FirebaseOptions but can I have two instances? Or what do you suggest?

```
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
    .setApplicationId("1:27992087142:android:ce3b6448250083d1") // Required for Analytics.
    .setApiKey("AIzaSyADUe90ULnQDuGShD9W23RDP0xmeDc6Mvw") // Required for Auth.
    .setDatabaseUrl("https://myproject.firebaseio.com") // Required for RTDB.
    .build();
```